# QCryptographicsHash gives different results for same string

Tags: c++, qt, md5

I have a QString with special symbols (czech diacritics etc.). I want to calculate checksum of this string in Qt, so I do:

```
QString createChecksum(QString str) {
  return QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(str.toLatin1(), QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex());
}
```

If I print str.toLatin1().data() using cout, I always get:

> roleadminmanageroperatorservicemanname10password10created16last_login16removable1last_iso_template10last_pcr_template10last_measurement10last_analysis10last_std_curve100�k��1���F������k��1���F�����140290845145014029084514500

However, for this string, code mentioned above gives different results (each number corresponds to one particular run of createCheckSum):

> 0x1e42da8 0x1e454a8 0x1e45438 0x1e45378 0x1e41678 0x1e49b58 0x1e49998

When I put the string into [online md5 tool](http://www.md5.cz/), I will always get same result:

> 6ac41fe9d5338d8aa7f7fb5027e2cdd2

Comment: are you copying the � signs as is, or do you use an appropriate character set?

Comment: yes I've copied them "as is"..these are exactly what I see in my console or what I pasted to that checksum generator

Comment: What you can try is to write the string in a file and view it with a (good) text editor. Depending on your system your console might not support unicode or utf8 output. This gives you at least a better start for comparsion

Comment: you can try to use your checksum function without special symbols and see if the output is still different, probably the problem is in the encoding

Comment: Yes you are right, the problem is in encoding. So my question is how can I calculate MD5SUM for QString with respect to encodings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toHex` can only return letters 0-9 and a-f. What you get (`0x1e42da8`) cannot be produced by this code. Please show your actual output statement. It seems that you print out some pointers instead of real data, and pointers tend to be random throughout restarts.

Also if your string can contain special symbols, you definitely should not use  `toLatin1()` as all symbols that are not present in Latin1 encoding will be lost. You should either use `QString::toUtf8()` or use `QTextCodec` for desired encoding to convert `QString` to `QByteArray`.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. First thing was to use Utf8 instead of Latin1 encoding. And second, I was converting result to wstring and this was the source of that nonses "0x1e42da8".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
return QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(str.toLatin1(), QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex());
```

try

```
return QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(str.toUtf8(), QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex());
```